# Is there a scientific explanation for these two cases of healing after intercessory prayer?

Tags: medical-science, miracle

I recently found two remarkable case reports of healings after intercessory prayer:

- [Case report of instantaneous resolution of juvenile macular degeneration blindness after proximal intercessory prayer](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1550830720300926)

  A young woman with a case of juvenile macular degeneration blindness was apparently cured (for 40 years) after a proximal intercessory prayer experience in 1972.
- [Case Report of gastroparesis healing: 16 years of a chronic syndrome resolved after proximal intercessory prayer](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0965229918313116)

  An infant was diagnosed with gastroparesis after an operation on his stomach. He needed to be fed through a tube into his abdomen until 16. In 2011, he had a proximal intercessory prayer experience. Then he was able to tolerate eating, and over the next 4 months, the tubes were removed, and he was symptom free for 7 years.

What could account for these cures?

Comment: Please include details from both sources in your question.  Both of them are long reports and we need to know the details that you are wondering about so we can answer your question.

Comment: They appear to be peer-reviewed papers. What do you expect a community of non-scientists are supposed to do?

Comment: These are case reports rather than scientific studies. Lead author Clarissa Gomez is from the Global Medical Research Institute, which describes itself as "a non-profit organization dedicated to understanding the science of healing through prayer." So these are people who believe prayer can heal writing up the accounts of people who think prayer healed them, in one case 47 years after the intercession.

Comment: Note: I removed the question "Are these paranormal?" because the obligation here to include references to empirical data makes the only possible answer to that to be "No".

Comment: Paranormal activity which you can measure and explain has a name: science.

Answer (score 14):

Medical science is messy. Sometimes diseases [just get better on their own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_remission), no matter what you do. Sometimes the act of treating people makes them feel (or report feeling) better, no matter what the treatment actually does.

These two case studies are [anecdotal evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdote#As_evidence). We will never be able to conclude from them alone that intercessory prayer helped. It may have been a coincidence. It may have been a mistake or a lie. It may have been some other confounding factor.

To address this, medical science uses [randomised, double-blind placebo-controlled trials](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3505292/).

There have been many attempts at such trials of intercessory prayer, with varying results. Why would results vary? The results may have been a random coincidence (and larger samples are required). It may have been a mistake, poor design or a lie by biased researchers.

To address this, medical science uses [systematic reviews](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/about/about-cochrane-reviews). Experts in research and statistics do a careful search for all of the studies in the literature, and evaluate them on strict criteria to eliminate bias and understand how reliable a conclusion may be. One of the most prominent sources of high-quality systematic reviews in medicine is the [Cochrane Library](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/).

In 2009, Cochrane published a relevant systematic review: [*Intercessory prayer for the alleviation of ill health*](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD000368.pub3/full)

This study included both proximal and non-proximal intercessory prayer:

> We included any randomised trial comparing personal, focused, committed and organised intercessory prayer with those interceding holding some belief that they are praying to God or a god versus any other intervention. This prayer could be offered on behalf of anyone with health problems.

They found 10 relevant studies, with varying results.

They found that using the data as reported:

- > no significant difference in recovery from illness or death between those prayed for and those not prayed for.
- no significant differences to post‐operative or other complications, indeterminate and bad outcomes, or readmission to hospital.
- > Specific complications (cardiac arrest, major surgery before discharge, need for a monitoring catheter in the heart) were significantly more likely to occur among those in the group not receiving prayer.
- fewer post‐operative complications in those who had no knowledge of being prayed for, compared with those who knew.

However, they were leery of trusting these results, because of the low quality of the studies. They concluded:

> it is only possible to state that intercessory prayer is neither significantly beneficial nor harmful for those who are sick. Further studies which are better designed and reported would be necessary to draw firmer conclusions.

They also recommend **not** following up with further studies, arguing that the resources used to further investigate could be better used in more promising areas.

In conclusion: based on the best research we have to date, intercessory prayer does not have any significant effect on the health of patients.

Comment: What I would like to know is why the people in these two case reports were healed

Comment: There is insufficient evidence to confirm a definitive reason for remission in these cases. Question cross-posted at [medical-sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31920/is-there-a-scientific-explanation-for-these-two-cases-of-mysterious-healing).  Please don't do that.

Comment: I'm just looking for possible reasons why the remission occurred...

Comment: @Panem this answer explains that sometimes people get better with no explanation.

Comment: @Panem: I explain "It may have been a coincidence. It may have been a mistake or a lie. It may have been some other confounding factor." and that "We will never be able to conclude from them alone that intercessory prayer helped." But given intercessory prayer doesn't work when scientists are carefully watching, it is reasonable to conclude it doesn't work at other times either.

Comment: I could speculate 20 reasons about what happened in these cases, but that would be off-topic. Here we expect references to support our claims

Comment: @Oddthinking - I think you might rephrase the last sentence to "...intercessory prayer does not have any significant **medical** effect on patients." As a physician and a human being, I know that there is many times a psychological benefit to the patient on the receiving end of prayer. (I see that you acknowledged a psychological benefit in your opening paragraph. Your summation contradicts this.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I agree that the study was about the physical health of the patient and not, for example, about the spiritual well-being, so I edited the answer. As a skeptic, I don't accept that there is a [measurable] *psychological* benefit without some evidence. One of the studies found *knowing* you were being prayed for was correlated with *more* complications, but the review authors didn't accept this as a strong conclusion, so I have to remain wary of that result.